my code to check for all possible combinations of a word using utf-16 characters is not doing anything
here is the code itself:
import itertools

def generate_utf16_combinations(word):
    word_chars = list(word)
    combos = []
    utf16_combos = []
    for i in range(1, len(word_chars) + 1):
        combos.extend(list(itertools.permutations(word_chars, i)))
    for combo in combos:
        utf16_combo = ''.join(combo).encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass')
        utf16_combos.append(utf16_combo)
    return utf16_combos

def generate_all_utf16_combinations(start, end, current_word, file_path, max_value):
    # Define ranges for Asian languages
    asian_ranges = [
        (0x1100, 0x11FF), # Hangul Jamo
        (0x2E80, 0x2EFF), # CJK Radicals Supplement
        (0x4E00, 0x9FFF), # CJK Unified Ideographs
        (0xAC00, 0xD7AF), # Hangul Syllables
        (0x3000, 0x303F), # CJK Symbols and Punctuation
        # other ranges of asian languages
        (0x2F00, 0x2FDF), (0x3040, 0x309F), (0x30A0, 0x30FF),
        (0x3100, 0x312F), (0x3190, 0x319F), (0x31C0, 0x31EF), (0x31F0, 0x31FF),
        (0x3200, 0x32FF), (0x3300, 0x33FF), (0x3400, 0x4DBF),
        (0xF900, 0xFAFF), (0xFE30, 0xFE4F), (0x20000, 0x2A6DF), (0x2A700, 0x2B73F),
        (0x2B740, 0x2B81F), (0x2B820, 0x2CEAF), (0x2CEB0, 0x2EBEF), (0x2F800, 0x2FA1F)
    ]

    def is_asian(code_point):
        # Check if the code point falls within any Asian range
        for start, end in asian_ranges:
            if start <= code_point <= end:
                return True
        return False

    def recursive_combinations(current_word, depth, file, count):
        if count >= max_value:
            return
        if depth == 0:
            return
        for code_point in range(start, end + 1):
            if is_asian(code_point):
                continue # Skip Asian characters
            char = chr(code_point)
            utf16_combos = generate_utf16_combinations(current_word + char)
            for combo in utf16_combos:
                file.write(combo + b", \n")
                count += 1
                if count >= max_value:
                    return
                recursive_combinations(current_word + char, depth - 1, file, count)

    # Check if there's a progress file
    try:
        with open(file_path + "_progress", "r") as progress_file:
            last_word = progress_file.read().strip()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        last_word = ""
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: ", e)
        return

    start_index = len(last_word) # Start generating combinations from the next character
    for char in word[start_index:]:
        utf16_combos = generate_utf16_combinations(current_word + char)
        for combo in utf16_combos:
            with open(file_path, "ab") as file:
                file.write(combo + b", \n")
                count += 1
                if count >= max_value:
                    return
        current_word += char

    # Update the progress file with the last processed word
    with open(file_path + "_progress", "w") as progress_file:
        progress_file.write(current_word)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Constants
    start = 0x0000
    end = 0x10FFFF
    file_path = "...documents/banned_words/banned_words_banana.txt"
    word = "banana"
    max_value = 1000

    # Function call
    generate_all_utf16_combinations(start, end, word, file_path, max_value)

Okay, so with that out of the way let me try to explain what I am trying to do: the "generate_utf16_combinations(word)" function creates a list of all possible permutations of a word (in this case "banana") given 1 character, which is fed inside of "generate_all_utf16_combinations", a recursive function.
"generate_all_utf16_combinations" tries to create a dictionary of tuples with all the ranges of languages inside of the asian continent, at least that was my intention and I tried to do this because without it, the code would be left running for hours and i would come back to one single file worth 300gb of gibberish and insanely long strings. So, this chunk of my code does not work but I wanted to include it nonetheless.
My code should skip all asian characters and try different combos of the word "banana" with as many special characters inside of utf-16 as it can, given 1000 iterations. In the "is_asian" function it sees if the character is inside the range of asian characters in utf-16.
Then, it basically the code takes a look to see if the word combination has been done already. if it has not, it goes to the next special weird character and tries a combination with it. It does this until the 1000 loops have been done. Saves the last word of the list of combinations inside of "banned_words_banana.txt_progress" and the rest of the list of words gets printed inside of "banned_words_banana.txt".
I am doing this because I mod a discord server and I would rather have a big list of naughty gamer words with weird characters inside of it, and run this thing every day until eventually i fill out a big chunk of options, rather than be stuck to the damned place 24/7 and waste my time. At least doing it this way I am learning a lot from it.
I first tried with a simple for loop that would take all possible combinations of a word, but if, for instance, it would try "apple", it would start with a, then ap, then app, appl, apple, appel, so on and so forth. I realized this is useless for my ends so I tried to use utf-16 so it would have a more vast array of special characters, such as vowels with accents or upside-down letters. Before my code would stop working, it would print out a BIG amount of mandarin special characters, but the sun is going to die before i am done with all possible combinations of all mandarin + the word banana. The more i spend writing the harder this seemingly simple task becomes.
So, whats the issue? Well, there's gotta be a way for me to code a script that will check the list of banned combinations of a single word and see for itself where did it left off. There's gotta be a way for me to keep a long file with all possible realistic combos of a word so my weird discord server does not get nuked to hell... again. As it is, right now my script does not skip special characters from japanese, mandarin, etc., it does not write anything on both text files and gets stuck in an infinite loop. I have not coded for a while so I need assistance.
If you've made it this far, i appreciate your time. Please lmk if you have any other questions.

What do you mean by "permutations of a word given 1 character"? Permutation meens reordering a sequence, so nabana is a permutation of banana.

What you probably want is a regular expression that matches bad words with extra characters betweenthe letters. E.g. b\W?a\W?n\W?a\W?n\W?a

@Barmar thank you! regular expressions seem to fall in line better with my goals.

I'm not sure what you mean by UTF-16 in this context, you aren't working with UTF-16 bytes, nor are you working with UTF-16 codepoints since there is no handling of surrogate pairs. Maybe just easier to restructure and rename functions for clarity. Also your concept of what constitutes Asian languages are limited. The code, for instance doesn't support all languages of china, let alone Asia.
